# How do I remove specific contents from a text file?

Tags: java, file, directory

I'm working on this project with some help from SO in java and I'm reading a folder which then writes the contents to a file. I then need to go through that content and only keep the image that has Thumbnail.jpg at the end.

**EDIT:**

```
 public static final File outFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/output.txt");

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    getFileContents();
}

public static void getFileContents() throws IOException{

    System.out.print(outFile.getAbsolutePath());
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outFile);

        Files.walk(Paths.get("C:/Location")).forEach(filePath -> {
            //this is where I would like to happen
            if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath)) // I was thinking I could use filePath.endsWith("Thumbnail.jpg")
                    out.println(filePath);
        }); 
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: A question that asks, "Am I on the right path?" is essentially asking for a code review.  There's a site that does that, but their requirement is that the question [meets their exacting standards](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  I don't believe that this particular question would be acceptable there, nor is it here; from what I can see it doesn't look like it compiles.

Comment: You can't compare strings using `!=`, you must use `! str.equals("T")`. Also, Strings are immutable, so `string.trim()` does nothing, you'll need to say `string = string.trim()`.

Comment: If you're look for string values ending in "Thumbnail.jpg", use `string.endsWith("Thumbnail.jpg")`.

Comment: You also seem to misunderstand `substring(start)`. It returns the remainder of the string, starting at the given position. If you only want the character at that position, use `string.charAt(start)`.

Comment: @Andreas ah shoot that's right, thanks

Comment: @Andreas So I could just use !string.endsWith("Thumbnail.jpg") in the if statement and remove everything else haha

Comment: That is correct. If that ends up being the answer to your question, you should answer your own question and accept that as the final answer, so others can easily see it.

Comment: @Andreas So far I haven't figured out all the bugs but I'll make sure to do that and are you sure you don't want to answer the question? You put in the vast majority of the work.

Comment: Oh, and you shouldn't ignore the "resource" warning. In this case it's telling you that you're not closing the Reader, which is very important to do, and very easily done using try-with-resources.

Comment: I would use a shell script.

Comment: @Bohemian what is a shell script, I thought that was something with just JavaScript but I know nothing about it?

Comment: It's a "command line" script (eg a bash script in linux, or a bat file in windows). While Java could do it, it may not be the right tool for what is an "operational" job. Something halfway between, like perl or python, might be a good choice.

Comment: @Bohemian oh ok that makes sense thanks for the help. I ended up finding a solution if you're curious at looking at it I posted in the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to thank everyone for the help but after a lot of trial and error I was able to find a solution to my problem. This is how I solved my problem, I created two methods

1. A method that creates a file with all the folders contents.
2. A method that takes this file and creates a new one with the
   selected content.

I then just called these with the main method. Then you would just proceed to delete your first file.

---

```
    // this is the input file from the folder
    public static final File outFile = new File("input.txt");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {     
        getFileContents();
        changeFileContents();
    }

    // this method takes all the folder contents and puts
    // it into a text file
    public static void getFileContents() throws IOException{

        System.out.print(outFile.getAbsolutePath());
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outFile);

            Files.walk(Paths.get("C:/Location")).forEach(file -> {
                if (Files.isRegularFile(file))
                        out.println(file);
            }); 
        out.close();
    }

    // this method takes the previously made text file and makes
    // a new one only adding the file names with Thumbnail.jpg
    public static void changeFileContents() throws IOException {

        PrintWriter in = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(outFile);
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                // checks to see if the image is the one I need
                if(line.contains("Thumbnail.jpg"))
                    in.println(line);
            }
        scanner.close();
        in.close();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args)  {
    // My test file. Change to your path 
    File file = new File("/home/andrew/Desktop/File.txt");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("File not found");
    }

    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

        //now read the file line by line...
        int lineNum = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            lineNum++;
            // If Thumbnail.jpg is anyone where on the line
            if(line.contains("Thumbnail.jpg")){
                // print the line for example. You can do whatever you what with it now 
                System.out.println("Found item on line: " +lineNum);
            }
        }
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) { 
        //handle this
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File inputFile = new File("File.txt");
File tempFile = new File("File1.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
String lineToRemove = "Thumbnil.jpg";
String currentLine;
 while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
if(trimmedLine.equals(lineToRemove)) continue;
writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
 }
writer.close(); 
reader.close(); 
boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
```